# perform sentiment analysis by propagating sentiment information through the graph convolutional network

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to perform sentiment analysis by propagating sentiment information through the graph convolutional network where I collected 112 tweet using twitter manually

This the code I am running but facing errors  and I can't get a GCN

please any help to fix it

```
`import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import networkx as nx
 import tensorflow as tf
 from tensorflow import keras
 from keras.layers import Input, Dense
 from keras.models import Model, Sequential
 from keras.optimizers import Adam
 from keras.regularizers import l2
 from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
 import torch`
```

## Load the dataset

```
`data = pd.read_excel("datayahudarihab.xlsx")`
```

## Preprocess the data

```
`data = data[['node_id', 'Sentiment', 'Source Node', 'Target Node', 'Weighted Edge']]
nodes = set(data['Source Node']).union(set(data['Target Node']))
node_to_index = {node: i for i, node in enumerate(nodes)}
data['Source Node'] = data['Source Node'].map(node_to_index)
data['Target Node'] = data['Target Node'].map(node_to_index)
num_nodes = len(nodes)
num_classes = len(set(data['Sentiment']))
features = torch.randn(num_nodes, 1)`
```

## Convert the dataframe to a networkx graph

```
`G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source="Source Node", target="Target Node", edge_attr=True)`
```

## Convert the graph to adjacency matrix

```
`A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)`
```

## Convert the features to a numpy array

```
`X = np.array(data[["Opinion Text", "Responder Name", "Response Text", "Respondent Name"]])`
```

## Split the data into train, validation and test sets

```
`X_train = X[:80]
 X_val = X[80:100]
 X_test = X[100:]`
```

## Define the model architecture

```
`model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(units=16, activation="relu", input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
 model.add(Dense(units=8, activation="relu"))
 model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="sigmoid"))`
```

## Compile the model

```
`model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])`
```

## Train the model

```
`early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=5)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_val, y_val),               callbacks=[early_stop])`
```

## Evaluate the model on the test set

```
`score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)`
```

## Make predictions on new data

`new_data = pd.read_excel("new_data.xlsx") predictions = model.predict(np.array(new_data[["Opinion Text", "Responder Name", "Response Text",   "Respondent Name"]]))`

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Is there a problem with your code? What's not working? how is it now working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask